# how to fix image positioning with css

Tags: html, css

I am working on a web application and I am trying to put image on right and left image like image below but it move the screen size. how to make image fix on left and right properly.

I am working on a web application and I am trying to put image on right and left image like image below but it move the screen size. how to make image fix on left and right properly.

[image]

```css
   
     * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      
      ul,
      nav {
        list-style: none;
      }
      
      .pricing * {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      
      section {
       align-items: center;
      }
    
    .bg-gray{
        background: #F2F2F2;
    }
    
    .container-fluid{
        background: #fff
    }
    
     
      .flex-container-ctrl {
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9;
      }
      
      .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        padding: 1.9em;
        max-width: 80%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      
      .flex-item {
        flex: 1;
        width: 0;
      }
      
      .flex-item:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 1.5em;
        width: 90%;
      }
      
      .package {
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        transition: 0.25s;
        border-radius: 12px;
      }
      
      /* .package:hover {
          box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          transform: scale(1.025);
        } */
      
      .package .header {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        height: 124px;
      }
      
      .package .highlight {
        background-color: #29b6f6;
        border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
      }
      
      .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Best Plan";
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 0;
        background: #ffb100;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #c18705;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 25px;
        width: 10%;
        margin: -45px 70px;
        position: absolute;
        /* top: 1px; */
        font-size: large;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        letter-spacing: 0.13em;
      }
      
      .package .pricing-title {
        float: left;
        height: 10px;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      
      .pricing-title .sub-pricing-title {
        font-size: 10px;
      }
      
      .pricing hr {
        margin: 1.5rem 0;
      }
      
      .pricing-title img{
        width: 19px;
        height: auto;
      }
      
      .package .ctrl-pricing {
        float: right;
        height: 10px;
      }
      
      .ctrl-pricing .sub-pricing-title {
        font-size: 10px;
      }
      
      .package li {
        background-color: #fff;
        /* border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; */
        padding: 1.2em;
        text-align: center;
        height: 20px;
      }
      
      .package .gray {
        /* background-color: #eee; */
        font-size: 1.25em;
        border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
        height: inherit;
        padding: 1.6em;
      }
      
      button {
        background: #015496;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 25px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0.51em 1.5em;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        z-index: 99;
      }
      .font-clr {
        color: #29b6f6;
      }
      
      .flower-right{
        width: 34em;
        height: 48em;
        right: 0em;
        bottom: 2px;
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ScMV83t.png); 
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position:relative;
        z-index: 0;
        top: -2px
      }
      
      #rightflower{
        background-position: 10px;
      }
      
      .flower-left{
        width: 34em;
        height: 51em;
        left: -9em;
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ttgZVYr.png); 
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        top: 15em;
        float: left;
      }
      
      #leftflower{
        background-position: 10px;
      }
      
      @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        button {
          padding: -0.25em;
        }
        .flex-container {
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .payment-method{
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
      
        .flex-item {
          flex: 0 0 100%;
          margin-bottom: 1em;
          width: 100%;
          padding-bottom: 20px
        }
        .flower-left,.flower-right{
          display: none;
        }
        .max-width{
          max-width: 71%;
        }
      
        .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
          width: 20%;
          margin: -39px 9em;
        }
      }
      
      @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        .flex-container {
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
      
        .flex-item {
          flex: 0 0 100%;
          margin-bottom: 1em;
          width: 100%;
        }
      
        .package:hover {
          box-shadow: none;
          transform: none;
        }
      
        button {
          padding: -0.25em 1.5em;
        }
      
        .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
          width: 20%;
          margin: -39px 6.5em;
        }
        .ctrl-button{
          padding: 2px 5px 0 5px !important;
        }
        .max-width{
          max-width: 75%;
        }
      }
```

```html
    <section class="pricing" id="pricing">
            <div class="flex-container-ctrl">
                <div class="flex-container">
                  <div class="flex-item">
                    <ul class="package">
                      <li class="header highlight">
                        <span class="pricing-title"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
                      </li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="gray">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
            
                  <div class="flex-item">
                   <ul class="package">
                      <li class="header highlight">
                        <span class="pricing-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
                      </li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="gray">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-item">
                    <ul class="package">
                      <li class="header highlight">
                        <span class="pricing-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
                      </li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="gray">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flower-right"  id="rightflower"></div>
            <div class="flower-left"  id="leftflower"></div>
        </section>
```

[`https://jsfiddle.net`](https://jsfiddle.net/shahjihan78/cvp3o482/24/)

hopefully anyone can help me to settle down my problem

Comment: Check the below snippet. I have just tweaked your position and applied transform property to make it to centre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `position:absolute` and `transform` property to your images in this way.

```
    .flower-right {
      width: 34em;
      height: 48em;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 2px;
      background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ScMV83t.png);
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 0;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%)
    }

    #rightflower {
      background-position: 10px;
    }

    .flower-left {
      width: 34em;
      height: 51em;
      left: 0;
      background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ttgZVYr.png);
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 0;
      top: 50%;
      transform: translateY(-50%)
    }

    #leftflower {
      background-position: 10px;
    }
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

ul,
nav {
  list-style: none;
}

.pricing * {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
  align-items: center;
}

.bg-gray {
  background: #F2F2F2;
}

.container-fluid {
  background: #fff
}

.flex-container-ctrl {
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 9;
}

.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 1.9em;
  max-width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1;
  width: 0;
}

.flex-item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1.5em;
  width: 90%;
}

.package {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  transition: 0.25s;
  border-radius: 12px;
}


/* .package:hover {
          box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          transform: scale(1.025);
        } */

.package .header {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  height: 124px;
}

.package .highlight {
  background-color: #29b6f6;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
}

.package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: "Best Plan";
  display: block;
  padding: 5px 0;
  background: #ffb100;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #c18705;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 10%;
  margin: -45px 70px;
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 1px; */
  font-size: large;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  letter-spacing: 0.13em;
}

.package .pricing-title {
  float: left;
  height: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.pricing-title .sub-pricing-title {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.pricing hr {
  margin: 1.5rem 0;
}

.pricing-title img {
  width: 19px;
  height: auto;
}

.package .ctrl-pricing {
  float: right;
  height: 10px;
}

.ctrl-pricing .sub-pricing-title {
  font-size: 10px;
}

.package li {
  background-color: #fff;
  /* border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; */
  padding: 1.2em;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
}

.package .gray {
  /* background-color: #eee; */
  font-size: 1.25em;
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
  height: inherit;
  padding: 1.6em;
}

button {
  background: #015496;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.51em 1.5em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  z-index: 99;
}

.font-clr {
  color: #29b6f6;
}

.flower-right {
  width: 34em;
  height: 48em;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 2px;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ScMV83t.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

#rightflower {
  background-position: 10px;
}

.flower-left {
  width: 34em;
  height: 51em;
  left: 0;
  background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ttgZVYr.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%)
}

#leftflower {
  background-position: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  button {
    padding: -0.25em;
  }
  .flex-container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .payment-method {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 20px
  }
  .flower-left,
  .flower-right {
    display: none;
  }
  .max-width {
    max-width: 71%;
  }
  .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
    width: 20%;
    margin: -39px 9em;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .flex-container {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flex-item {
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .package:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
    transform: none;
  }
  button {
    padding: -0.25em 1.5em;
  }
  .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
    width: 20%;
    margin: -39px 6.5em;
  }
  .ctrl-button {
    padding: 2px 5px 0 5px !important;
  }
  .max-width {
    max-width: 75%;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="pricing" id="pricing">
  <div class="flex-container-ctrl">
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="flex-item">
        <ul class="package">
          <li class="header highlight">
            <span class="pricing-title"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
          </li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="gray">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="flex-item">
        <ul class="package">
          <li class="header highlight">
            <span class="pricing-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
          </li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="gray">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-item">
        <ul class="package">
          <li class="header highlight">
            <span class="pricing-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
          </li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
          <li class="gray">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flower-right" id="rightflower"></div>
  <div class="flower-left" id="leftflower"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: I have used transform property to make your images to be centred in all the screens. If you want to place  somewhere like top:30px. Then you can remove the transform property and set top and left according to your requirement. Hope you get it.happy coding

Answer (score 0):

We need adjust `position`, Please check fiddle.

[View Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j7xyr084/)

Comment: Thank you for answer... i dont want to use `position: fixed;`

Comment: Without position you want be able to get required behavior.

Comment: i mean.. i want to use `position:relative` or `position:abselutly`

Answer (score 0):

You've posted a lot of code here and will need to remove the background colour of the main page yourself but other than that this will work.

Create a div called `background` and set `z-index` to `-1` and then do the same for `pagebody` and set `z-index` to `1`. That should do the trick. Just set the background div to have a background image or place an image inside the DIV at `100%` width and height.

```css
.background {
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url("https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/94/75/70/240_F_194757077_Lv4ZT8XAOQRerY0vTA4grbAEwTHU9srK.jpg")
}
}

.pagebody {
  z-index: 1;
}
     
     
     * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
      }
      
      
      ul,
      nav {
        list-style: none;
      }
      
      .pricing * {
        margin: 0 auto;
      }
      
      section {
       align-items: center;
      }
    
    .bg-gray{
        background: #F2F2F2;
    }
    
    .container-fluid{
        background: #fff
    }
    
     
      .flex-container-ctrl {
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        z-index: 9;
      }
      
      .flex-container {
        display: flex;
        padding: 1.9em;
        max-width: 80%;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 1;
      }
      
      .flex-item {
        flex: 1;
        width: 0;
      }
      
      .flex-item:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: 1.5em;
        width: 90%;
      }
      
      .package {
        border: 1px solid #eee;
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        transition: 0.25s;
        border-radius: 12px;
      }
      
      /* .package:hover {
          box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
          transform: scale(1.025);
        } */
      
      .package .header {
        color: #fff;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        height: 124px;
      }
      
      .package .highlight {
        background-color: #29b6f6;
        border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
      }
      
      .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
        content: "Best Plan";
        display: block;
        padding: 5px 0;
        background: #ffb100;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #c18705;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 25px;
        width: 10%;
        margin: -45px 70px;
        position: absolute;
        /* top: 1px; */
        font-size: large;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        letter-spacing: 0.13em;
      }
      
      .package .pricing-title {
        float: left;
        height: 10px;
        font-size: 17px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
      
      .pricing-title .sub-pricing-title {
        font-size: 10px;
      }
      
      .pricing hr {
        margin: 1.5rem 0;
      }
      
      .pricing-title img{
        width: 19px;
        height: auto;
      }
      
      .package .ctrl-pricing {
        float: right;
        height: 10px;
      }
      
      .ctrl-pricing .sub-pricing-title {
        font-size: 10px;
      }
      
      .package li {
        background-color: #fff;
        /* border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; */
        padding: 1.2em;
        text-align: center;
        height: 20px;
      }
      
      .package .gray {
        /* background-color: #eee; */
        font-size: 1.25em;
        border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
        height: inherit;
        padding: 1.6em;
      }
      
      button {
        background: #015496;
        border: none;
        border-radius: 25px;
        color: #fff;
        cursor: pointer;
        padding: 0.51em 1.5em;
        font-size: 16px;
        font-weight: bold;
        z-index: 99;
      }
      .font-clr {
        color: #29b6f6;
      }
      
      .flower-right{
        width: 34em;
        height: 48em;
        right: 0em;
        bottom: 2px;
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ScMV83t.png); 
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position:relative;
        z-index: 0;
        top: -2px
      }
      
      #rightflower{
        background-position: 10px;
      }
      
      .flower-left{
        width: 34em;
        height: 51em;
        left: -9em;
        background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ttgZVYr.png); 
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: relative;
        z-index: 0;
        top: 15em;
        float: left;
      }
      
      #leftflower{
        background-position: 10px;
      }
      
      @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        button {
          padding: -0.25em;
        }
        .flex-container {
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        .payment-method{
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
      
        .flex-item {
          flex: 0 0 100%;
          margin-bottom: 1em;
          width: 100%;
          padding-bottom: 20px
        }
        .flower-left,.flower-right{
          display: none;
        }
        .max-width{
          max-width: 71%;
        }
      
        .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
          width: 20%;
          margin: -39px 9em;
        }
      }
      
      @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
        .flex-container {
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
      
        .flex-item {
          flex: 0 0 100%;
          margin-bottom: 1em;
          width: 100%;
        }
      
        .package:hover {
          box-shadow: none;
          transform: none;
        }
      
        button {
          padding: -0.25em 1.5em;
        }
      
        .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
          width: 20%;
          margin: -39px 6.5em;
        }
        .ctrl-button{
          padding: 2px 5px 0 5px !important;
        }
        .max-width{
          max-width: 75%;
        }
      }
```

```html
<div class="background">
<!-- You don't need anything here unless you place the background image here rather than as a CSS background image. -->
</div>

<div class="pagebody">
<section class="pricing" id="pricing">
            <div class="flex-container-ctrl">
                <div class="flex-container">
                  <div class="flex-item">
                    <ul class="package">
                      <li class="header highlight">
                        <span class="pricing-title"> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
                      </li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="gray">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
            
                  <div class="flex-item">
                   <ul class="package">
                      <li class="header highlight">
                        <span class="pricing-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
                      </li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="gray">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-item">
                    <ul class="package">
                      <li class="header highlight">
                        <span class="pricing-title">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
                      </li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="gray">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flower-right"  id="rightflower"></div>
            <div class="flower-left"  id="leftflower"></div>
        </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

change position to absolute

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  
  ul,
  nav {
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .pricing * {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  section {
   align-items: center;
  }

.bg-gray{
    background: #F2F2F2;
}

.container-fluid{
    background: #fff
}

/*----------------------
  pricing section 
----------------------*/

 /* .pricing {
   margin: 0 auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    font-family: lato;
    z-index: -2
  }*/

  
  .flex-container-ctrl {
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
  }
  
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    padding: 1.9em;
    max-width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .flex-item {
    flex: 1;
    width: 0;
  }
  
  .flex-item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    width: 90%;
  }
  
  .package {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.25s;
    border-radius: 12px;
  }
  
  /* .package:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transform: scale(1.025);
    } */
  
  .package .header {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 124px;
  }
  
  .package .highlight {
    background-color: #29b6f6;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  }
  
  .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
    content: "Best Plan";
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background: #ffb100;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #c18705;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 10%;
    margin: -45px 70px;
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 1px; */
    font-size: large;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
  }
  
  .package .pricing-title {
    float: left;
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .pricing-title .sub-pricing-title {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .pricing hr {
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
  }
  
  .pricing-title img{
    width: 19px;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .package .ctrl-pricing {
    float: right;
    height: 10px;
  }
  
  .ctrl-pricing .sub-pricing-title {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .package li {
    background-color: #fff;
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; */
    padding: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
  }
  
  .package .gray {
    /* background-color: #eee; */
    font-size: 1.25em;
    border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
    height: inherit;
    padding: 1.6em;
  }
  
  button {
    background: #015496;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.51em 1.5em;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  .font-clr {
    color: #29b6f6;
  }
  
  .flower-right{
    width: 34em;
    height: 48em;
    right: 0em;
    bottom: 2px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ScMV83t.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -2px;
  }
  
  #rightflower{
    background-position: 10px;
  }
  
  .flower-left{
    width: 34em;
    height: 51em;
    left: 0em;
    bottom: 2px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ttgZVYr.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0em;
    float: left;
  }
  
  #leftflower{
    background-position: 10px;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    button {
      padding: -0.25em;
    }
    .flex-container {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .payment-method{
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  
    .flex-item {
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 20px
    }
    .flower-left,.flower-right{
      display: none;
    }
    .max-width{
      max-width: 71%;
    }
  
    .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
      width: 20%;
      margin: -39px 9em;
    }
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .flex-container {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  
    .flex-item {
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      width: 100%;
    }
  
    .package:hover {
      box-shadow: none;
      transform: none;
    }
  
    button {
      padding: -0.25em 1.5em;
    }
  
    .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
      width: 20%;
      margin: -39px 6.5em;
    }
    .ctrl-button{
      padding: 2px 5px 0 5px !important;
    }
    .max-width{
      max-width: 75%;
    }
  }
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  
  ul,
  nav {
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  .pricing * {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  
  section {
   align-items: center;
  }

.bg-gray{
    background: #F2F2F2;
}

.container-fluid{
    background: #fff
}

/*----------------------
  pricing section 
----------------------*/

 /* .pricing {
   margin: 0 auto;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
    font-family: lato;
    z-index: -2
  }*/

  
  .flex-container-ctrl {
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 9;
  }
  
  .flex-container {
    display: flex;
    padding: 1.9em;
    max-width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  
  .flex-item {
    flex: 1;
    width: 0;
  }
  
  .flex-item:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 1.5em;
    width: 90%;
  }
  
  .package {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    transition: 0.25s;
    border-radius: 12px;
  }
  
  /* .package:hover {
      box-shadow: 0 8px 12px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      transform: scale(1.025);
    } */
  
  .package .header {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    height: 124px;
  }
  
  .package .highlight {
    background-color: #29b6f6;
    border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
  }
  
  .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
    content: "Best Plan";
    display: block;
    padding: 5px 0;
    background: #ffb100;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 0 #c18705;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 10%;
    margin: -45px 70px;
    position: absolute;
    /* top: 1px; */
    font-size: large;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    letter-spacing: 0.13em;
  }
  
  .package .pricing-title {
    float: left;
    height: 10px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  
  .pricing-title .sub-pricing-title {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .pricing hr {
    margin: 1.5rem 0;
  }
  
  .pricing-title img{
    width: 19px;
    height: auto;
  }
  
  .package .ctrl-pricing {
    float: right;
    height: 10px;
  }
  
  .ctrl-pricing .sub-pricing-title {
    font-size: 10px;
  }
  
  .package li {
    background-color: #fff;
    /* border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; */
    padding: 1.2em;
    text-align: center;
    height: 20px;
  }
  
  .package .gray {
    /* background-color: #eee; */
    font-size: 1.25em;
    border-radius: 0 0 12px 12px;
    height: inherit;
    padding: 1.6em;
  }
  
  button {
    background: #015496;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0.51em 1.5em;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    z-index: 99;
  }
  .font-clr {
    color: #29b6f6;
  }
  
  .flower-right{
    width: 34em;
    height: 48em;
    right: 0em;
    bottom: 2px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ScMV83t.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: -2px;
  }
  
  #rightflower{
    background-position: 10px;
  }
  
  .flower-left{
    width: 34em;
    height: 51em;
    left: 0em;
    bottom: 2px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/ttgZVYr.png);
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
    top: 0em;
    float: left;
  }
  
  #leftflower{
    background-position: 10px;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    button {
      padding: -0.25em;
    }
    .flex-container {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .payment-method{
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  
    .flex-item {
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      width: 100%;
      padding-bottom: 20px
    }
    .flower-left,.flower-right{
      display: none;
    }
    .max-width{
      max-width: 71%;
    }
  
    .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
      width: 20%;
      margin: -39px 9em;
    }
  }
  
  @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    .flex-container {
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
  
    .flex-item {
      flex: 0 0 100%;
      margin-bottom: 1em;
      width: 100%;
    }
  
    .package:hover {
      box-shadow: none;
      transform: none;
    }
  
    button {
      padding: -0.25em 1.5em;
    }
  
    .package .heading:nth-of-type(1):before {
      width: 20%;
      margin: -39px 6.5em;
    }
    .ctrl-button{
      padding: 2px 5px 0 5px !important;
    }
    .max-width{
      max-width: 75%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<section class="pricing" id="pricing">
            <div class="flex-container-ctrl">
                <div class="flex-container">
                  <div class="flex-item">
                    <ul class="package">
                      <li class="header highlight">
                        <span class="pricing-title"><i class="img-fire"><img
                              src="../../../../assets/img/fire-icon-563.png"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
                      </li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="gray">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
            
                  <div class="flex-item">
                   <ul class="package">
                      <li class="header highlight">
                        <span class="pricing-title"><i class="img-fire"><img
                              src="../../../../assets/img/fire-icon-563.png"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
                      </li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="gray">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="flex-item">
                    <ul class="package">
                      <li class="header highlight">
                        <span class="pricing-title"><i class="img-fire"><img
                              src="../../../../assets/img/fire-icon-563.png"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;
                          <p class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span><span class="ctrl-pricing"> &nbsp;&nbsp;<p
                            class="sub-pricing-title "> &nbsp;&nbsp;</p></span>
                      </li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="font-clr"> &nbsp;&nbsp;</li>
                      <li class="gray">
                          &nbsp;&nbsp;
                      </li>
                    </ul>
                  </div>
                  
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="flower-right"  id="rightflower"></div>
            <div class="flower-left"  id="leftflower"></div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You've posted a lot of code here and will need to remove the background colour of the main page yourself but other than that this will work.

Create a div called `background` and set `z-index` to `-1` and then do the same for `pagebody` and set `z-index` to `1`. That should do the trick. Just set the background div to have a background image or place an image inside the DIV at `100%` width and height.

```css
.background {
  z-index: -1;
  background-image: url("https://t3.ftcdn.net/jpg/01/94/75/70/240_F_194757077_Lv4ZT8XAOQRerY0vTA4grbAEwTHU9srK.jpg")
}
}

.pagebody {
  z-index: 1;
}
     
\* Rest of CSS *\
```

```html
<div class="background">
<!-- You don't need anything here unless you place the background image here rather than as a CSS background image. -->
</div>

<div class="pagebody">
<!-- Page body here. -->
</div>
```

I can't include all of your code because it marks as a duplicate. You could also create a left and a right DIV for the background at 50% each.